# Good introductory books on homological algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homological-algebra, big-list, learning

Which books would you recommend, for self-studying homological algebra, to a beginning graduate (or advanced undergraduate) student who has background in ring theory, modules, basic commutative algebra (some of Atiyah & Macdonald's book) and some (basic) field theory?

I would especially like to hear your opinions on the following books:

**A Course On Homological Algebra / P. J Hilton and U. Stambach**

**Introduction to Homological Algebra / Szen-Tsen Hu**

**Notes on Homological Algebra / Rotman**

But other recommendations will also be appreciated.

Comment: Weibel immediately comes to mind, it is a bit more advanced than the three books you mention. It's definitely worth looking into the eponymous Cartan-Eilenberg (the book that named and started the subject) and see how little has changed.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2533/homological-algebra-texts

Comment: By the way, does anyone know of a homological algebra text which is elementary in the sense that it only discusses homology and cohomology for $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (i.e. abelian groups)?

Comment: Rotman has a larger book that I think is a better introduction to the subject. It is large, but rather nice.

Comment: Mildly off-topic, but: I just noticed this strange tag "self-learning".  Is there some other kind of learning??

Comment: I think it just means that he intends on using the book purely on his own and not in conjunction with a course.

Comment: @Sean: probably this one: http://wwwdev.maa.org/maa%20reviews/01215.html

Comment: @Sean Complete agreement- Rotman's new edition of his classic is the definitive introduction for beginners to the subject.@t.b. Weibel is wonderful for it's modern, topologically rooted approach-but I think the average beginner is going to find it very tough going. I would recommend Rotman first, then Weibel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See also *A first course of homological algebra* by Northcott. There's a list in this [review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1988048) if you have access to MathSciNet.

Answer (score 4):

See "An introduction to homological algebra" of Rotman (2010). I think this is the book Mark was talking about. It is VERY introductory.