# Where to go to learn Homological Algebra

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Well, the problem is: I'm doing graduate studies in math, my current research theme is deformation quantization and, more in general, star products. I could reach some part of the area, principally star products. But I know nothing of homological algebra (nor Algebraic Topology, but I'll start sutdying algebraic topology as soon as possible).

So, my question is: Where can I learn homological algebra focused on this area, I mean principally Hochschild homology/cohomology.

If the text contain any gramatical errors, I apologize, now it's 4am (but it's not the end of december) in Sao Paulo.

Comment: For a list of introductory homological algebra books/notes see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28646/good-introductory-books-on-homological-algebra) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2533/homological-algebra-texts). May be others can guide you for more specialized areas (as you have asked).

Comment: I've already saw this posts and searched these books, at least the ones availables to me. So I'm now looking for something more specialized for what I need.