# Beginner's guide on homological algebra for commutative ring settings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, book-recommendation

At the moment, I'm a masters student, and I find commutative algebra to be pretty fascinating. The first seven chapters of "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah & Macdonald, "Steps in Commutative Algebra" by R.Y. Sharp, and the first three chapters of "Commutative Ring Theory" by Matsumura make up my foundational knowledge. My objective is to learn some homological algebra so that I can study it in greater depth and with greater interest in other books like "Cohen Macaulay Rings" by Bruns and Herzog. Which introductory book on it would be the best for me to read on my own? Algebraic topology is not my area of expertise.

Comment: I would recommend *An introduction to homological algebra* by Weibel. Some more recommendations are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28646/good-introductory-books-on-homological-algebra).

Comment: Hm... I disagree with the vote to close, since I think this is asking specifically about homological methods in commutative algebra. Regardless, I'll say that I've heard good things about Ferretti's [_Homological Methods in Commutative Algebra_](https://bookstore.ams.org/GSM-234). I've also personally read (and been in the class for) Grifo's [_Commutative and Homological Algebra_](https://eloisagrifo.github.io/CHAnotes.pdf), both of these are more focused on topics I think OP will find interesting than more general references like Weibel (which is obviously still a staple)

Comment: I think the question is very similar to  [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28646/good-introductory-books-on-homological-algebra), where the requirement is also   "background in ring theory, modules, basic commutative algebra (some of Atiyah & Macdonald's book) and some (basic) field theory". It seems that the list for books on "homological algebra" and for books on "homological algebra in the commutative ring setting" is not so different after all.  The books there mostly use purely algebraic methods, and are much closer to commutative algebra than to algebraic topology.